# Add a set amount of random Numbers in an array list while removing duplicates

Tags: java, arraylist, random

I can't seem to figure out why it lets duplicates pass. I thought my code implies that I do not want it to have any duplicates. The way I have my code now will add 7 random numbers to my ArrayList which is fine but it also adds duplicate which is not.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class LotteryNumbers {
    private ArrayList<Integer> numbers;


    public LotteryNumbers() {

        this.drawNumbers();
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> numbers() {

       Random randomizer = new Random(); 


        int i = 1;
        while (i <= 7) {

        if (!numbers.contains(randomizer.nextInt(39 + 1))); {

        numbers.add(randomizer.nextInt(39) + 1); 
        i++; 

        }

        }
        return this.numbers;
    }

    public void drawNumbers() {

        this.numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    }


}
```

Comment: Are you using java-8?

Comment: Nope I'm doing a course which uses NetBeans and it's java 6 I think

Comment: Shouldn't you reuse value of `nextInt(...)` because you're spawning another random number ?

Comment: Too bad. Put this in your pocket for later: `List<Integer> numbers = ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(1,41).distinct().limit(7).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Would using a `Set<Integer>` instead of `List<Integer>` be okay? You could keep adding until `numbers.size() == 7`.

Comment: You’re calling `randomizer.nextInt()` twice (even differently, I suspect it’s an error), and it will most often give you two different numbers from the two calls. If the first number is not already in `numbers`, you add the second. That’s no effective prevention of duplicates. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your `numbers()` method as follow

```
public ArrayList<Integer> numbers() {

    Random randomizer = new Random(); 

    int i = 1;
    int num;

    while (i <= 7) {

        num = randomizer.nextInt(39 + 1);

        if (!numbers.contains(num)); {
            numbers.add(num); 
            i++; 
        }

    }

    return this.numbers;
}
```